# How to extract links from an inframe?

Tags: json, callback, jsonp, postmessage

what I'm trying to do is extract link(s) from a google ad box, I tried it with jQuery and I'm getting an error when trying to run it, here's the code:

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById("aswift_0");
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow;
    // Get HTML element
    var iframeHtml = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1];
    $(iframeHtml).contents().find("textarea").keydown(...)
    var iframeDoc2 = iframeHtml.contentDocument || 
    iframeHtml.contentWindow;
    var iframeHtml2 = iframeDoc2.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

I get this error because I can't access the cross domain, I read that it's possible to extract the link(s) using JSONP callback function or post message, does, can someone help me with the code or know how to extract a link from an inframe. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. This is cross domain access and your browser will block it.

Comment: And he can't bypass cross domain, right now i read something about JSON and Post Message, and here it's look like you can bypass crossdomain access with  JSONP and/or Post Message..

Comment: You can bypass cross domain in cross domain allowed by domain :)